# Well,he's last or coming in last (while the race is still going on)

Tags: word-usage, american-english

My Aunt called up to ask me where my cousin was in the race.(She couldn't come to see it). The race was still going on so I tell her his current position, so what should I use:

> He's first/second/last(or ant other position).

Or

> He's coming in last(any position)

And in AmE is "position" used for different places in a race? Do they sound natural?

Answer (score 1):

You could say

> He is in the lead.
>
> He is in second **place** right now.
>
> He is probably coming in last.

In BrE at least, we say **place** to mean the position during or after a race, but in motor racing for example we say

> He is in pole **position**.

to indicate the advantage being given at the start.

Comment: can't it be : "He's in the last place right now." And what about: "He's coming in second place right now."

Comment: I was phrasing in different ways, bearing in mind the race is still on. "He's in the last place right now" is good (see my example), and the second would work if the race is finishing just as you are speaking, otherwise he isn't "coming in".